# Numpy np.r_ not working as expected with columns of dates turning them into long integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I have certain columns which data are dates. I have two types of datasets which I transform in separate scripts as a requirement.

These dates when parsed look as follows, and are of `dtype: object`.

| A_date | B_date | C_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 00:00:00 | 2023-04-23 00:00:00 | 2023-04-17 00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-20 00:00:00 | 2023-04-30 00:00:00 | 2023-04-24 00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-20 00:00:00 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |

When I run something like below using Numpy `np.r_`, the dates are converted as expected to something like `2022-12-20` which allows me to continue with other transformations.

```
pd_df.iloc[:, np.r_[5:7,9]] = pd_df.iloc[:, np.r_[5:7,9]].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors = 'coerce')
```

With the other dataset applying the same method is causing the values to turn into long `integer` values, but I cannot identify the source of the issue.

| A_date | B_date | C_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1681689600000000000 | 1691712000000000000 | 1681689600000000000 |
| 1681689600000000000 | 1691712000000000000 | 1682294400000000000 |
| 1681689600000000000 | 1691712000000000000 | 1682899200000000000 |

Comment: Isn't the `np.r_[5:7,9]` just producing `np.array([5,6,9])`?

Comment: if I run it as `pd_df[pd_df.columns[[5,6,9]]]`, then it works, ut this isn´t needed for the other dataset which gives me the problem of not reproducibility.